# How can I see which error is from which browser with Protractor with selenium grid

Tags: protractor, selenium-grid

We're running Protractor with Selenium Grid, with (for now) 2 browsers. When tests fail I see that they fail, and I see how many tests fail on each browser but somehow I cannot see on which browser the tests fail.
Is this a Selenium or a Protractor shortcoming or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you use jasmine reporters? I find the console indicates clear enough in which browser the error originates. And of course the html report is very clear.

Comment: no I did not, installed protractor-html-screenshot-reporter and that gives the expected feedback. Too bad it's not reported by Protractor's output itself though.

Comment: btw, add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use jasmine reporters? I find the console indicates clear enough in which browser the error originates. And of course the html report is very clear.

Add these in the protractor.conf.js in the onprepare block like this.

```
onPrepare: function () {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.ConsoleReporter());


    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: 'reports/screenshots'   ,
        takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
    }));

},
```

Be sure to use jasmine-reporters ~0.4.0 ,the 1.0.0 does not work yet with protractor because it work with a newer jasmine version then protractor until now uses.